# Html5/javascript/easeljs game project.Lots of code.I need a way out

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas, easeljs

I am working on a card game with HTML5 canvas and javascript with create.js library. The problem i have is that, I have an onclick function that deletes the clicked card from player's hand(removes the object from the array with splice and then redraws the canvas/redraws on canvas the new array of player's cards without the deleted one). When i do this for first time it does well.But if I click again on the card that it should be for example at index 1 in the array(after the splice method) it doesn't work.

Look at this code:

Here is my code for class Card:

```
function Card(suit,rank,imageFrontUrl,imageBackUrl)

{


     this.imageFront = new createjs.Bitmap(imageFrontUrl);
     this.imageBack = new createjs.Bitmap(imageBackUrl);
     this.suit = suit;
     this.rank = rank;

}
function Deck(){

this.cards = new Array();

this.makeDeck = function()
{
    this.cards[0]= new Card("clubs",1,"images/114.png","images/155.png");
    this.cards[1]= new Card("clubs",2,"images/115.png","images/155.png");
    this.cards[2]= new Card("clubs",3,"images/116.png","images/155.png");
    this.cards[3]= new Card("clubs",4,"images/117.png","images/155.png");
    this.cards[4]= new Card("clubs",5,"images/118.png","images/155.png");
    this.cards[5]= new Card("clubs",6,"images/119.png","images/155.png");
    ...

}


this.shuffleDeck = function()

{
    var j,k;

     for (j = 0; j < this.cards.length; j++) {
      k = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.cards.length);
      temp = this.cards[j];
      this.cards[j] = this.cards[k];
      this.cards[k] = temp;
    }

}   

this.dealCardsPlayer = function()
{ 
   var playerDeck = new Array();

  for(var i = 0; i<6;i++)
  {
    var x = this.cards.pop();
    playerDeck.push(x);

  }

  return playerDeck;

}
}
```

Here is my code for class Player:

```
function Player()
{

    this.playerTurn = false;
    this.id = this;
    this.name = this;
    this.score = this;
    this.playerHand = new Array();
    this.playerTakenCards = new Array();
    this.playerPickCard = function(n)
    {
    var card = this.playerHand(n);
        return card;


    }
    this.tempArray = this;}
```

Here is my init function:

```
function init(){
            var canvas = document.getElementById("tutorialCanvas");
            var stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
         var deck = new Deck();
            var player1 = new Player();
            deck.makeDeck();
            deck.shuffleDeck();
            player1.playerHand = deck.dealCardsPlayer();

  function drawPlayerCards(){
            var rotation=280;
            for(var i =0;i<player1.playerHand.length;i++)
            {

                player1.playerHand[i].imageFront.x=330;
                player1.playerHand[i].imageFront.y=750;
                player1.playerHand[i].imageFront.regX = 0;
                player1.playerHand[i].imageFront.regY = 96;
                player1.playerHand[i].imageFront.rotation = rotation;
                rotation = player1.playerHand[i].imageFront.rotation+20;
                stage.addChild(player1.playerHand[i].imageFront);


            }


            }

createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);}
```

And here is the function i have problem with:

```
player1.playerHand[1].imageFront.addEventListener('click',function(event)


            {   
                stage.removeAllChildren();

                player1.playerHand.splice(1,1);
drawTableDeck();

                drawPlayerCards();


            }
```

After some researching I realized that the function works just for the first bitmap player1.playerHand[1].imageFront . If i change the array with the first onclick event and after that player1.playerHand[1].imageFront is some other image/bitmap, it doesn't work for it. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you "hardcoding" the index of a card in your hand?

```
player1.playerHand.forEach(function(card) {
    card.imageFront.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var index = player1.playerHand.indexOf(card);

        if (index != -1) {
            stage.removeAllChildren();
            player1.playerHand.splice(index, 1);
            drawPlayerCards();
        }
    });
});
```

Some other notes:

- It's a convention to use `[]` instead of `new Array()`
- We normally put the opening brace `{` on the same line
- Your `Player` constructor has an error: `this.playerHand[n]` instead of `this.playerHand(n)`